# btnCalculate_onclick is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a page that when a user inputs the width and length, it calculates perimeter in a textbox.  Also, with the area.  Here is the code I have so far, I keep getting btnCalculate_onclick() is undefined.

```
<script src="Lab2-AreaPerimeter.js"></script>

    <p>
        Length:<input type="text" id="txtLength">
        <br>
        Width:<input type="text" id="txtWidth">
    </p>
    <p>
        Area:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="txtArea">
        <br>
        Perimeter:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="txtPerimeter">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="btnCalculate_onclick()" onclick="btnCalculate_onclick()">
        <input type="reset">
    </p>
</form>
<noscript>This website requires JavaScript to be enabled.</noscript>
```

javascript:

```
function btnCalculate_onclick()
{
    // get textboxes and assign to variables
    var lengthTextbox = document.getElementById("txtLength");
    var widthTextbox = document.getElementById("txtWidth");
    var areaTextbox = document.getElementById("txtArea");
    var perimeterTextbox = document.getElementById("txtPerimeter");

    //get user input value from corresponding textboxes
    var num1 - lengthTextbox.value;
    var num2 - secondTextbox.value;

    //calculate and display the sum
    var sum= num1 * 2 + num2 * 2
    sumPerimeterTextbox.value=sum
}
```

Comment: Is that the complete code? There is a syntax error, a missing "}"

Comment: Sorry I have that in the code, just had a problem getting it to the webpage

Comment: btnCalculate_onclick is inside lab2-AreaPerimeter.js ?

Comment: variables num1/num2 need equals sign not minus as well

Comment: yeah its on top of the code as function btnCalculate_onclick().  I changed to equal signs still no dice

Comment: Are the variables named `secondTextbox` and `sumPerimeterTextbox` declared somewhere?

Comment: Adam, check my answer, the problem was that you were using the same name for the element ID and the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jo1107jq/1/

I cleaned up your `btnCalculate_onclick` function and some of the html:

```
function btnCalculate_onclick() {
// get textboxes and assign to variables
    var lengthTextbox = document.getElementById("txtLength");
    var widthTextbox = document.getElementById("txtWidth");
    var areaTextbox = document.getElementById("txtArea");
    var perimeterTextbox = document.getElementById("txtPerimeter");

    //get user input value from corresponding textboxes
    var num1 = lengthTextbox.value;
    var num2 = widthTextbox.value;

    //calculate and display the sum
    var sum= num1 * 2 + num2 * 2
    perimeterTextbox.value=sum
}
```

Your script src might be incorrect and that is why it is saying the function is undefined.

Is your `Lab2-AreaPerimeter.js` file in the same directory as your web page?

Have you tried to troubleshoot with the browser developer tools?

You can try some of these things:

- Make sure that your JS file loaded correctly in the developer tools console.  If it doesn't, you should see something like: GET .../Lab2-AreaPerimeter.js 404 (Not Found)
- Put a break point in your `btnCalculate_onclick` function.
- Throw an `alert()` or `console.log()` at the start of your `btnCalculate_onclick` function and see if there is output.
- Define the function in script tags on your page and make sure it runs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example. Each element in your document will be a JS object named as of it's ID, So you shouldn't name a function just like an element ID.

```
<form>
    <p>
        Length:<input type="text" id="txtLength">
        <br>
        Width:<input type="text" id="txtWidth">
    </p>
    <p>
        Area:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="txtArea">
        <br>
        Perimeter:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="txtPerimeter">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="btbCalculate" onclick="btbCalculate_onclick()">
        <input type="reset">
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function btbCalculate_onclick() {
            // get textboxes and assign to variables
            var lengthTextbox = document.getElementById("txtLength");
            var widthTextbox = document.getElementById("txtWidth");
            var areaTextbox = document.getElementById("txtArea");
            var perimeterTextbox = document.getElementById("txtPerimeter");
            //get user input value from corresponding textboxes
            var num1 = lengthTextbox.value;
            var num2 = widthTextbox.value;
            //calculate and display the sum
            var sum = num1 * 2 + num2 * 2;
            perimeterTextbox.value = sum;
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that a element's `id` and a function's name couldn't be the same. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer. @adamMain check my answer, It is explained why your the function was undefined!